# Convert alphabetic letters to their relative position in the alphabet (R)

Tags: r

I would like to get the relative position in the alphabet of each letter in a string. To demonstrate something not working properly:

```
which(letters %in% unlist(strsplit("acba", split="")))
```

result:

```
#[1] 1 2 3
```

I'm looking for a code snippet returning:

```
#[1] 1 3 2 1
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we need to replace the string elements with numbers, `chartr` can be used

```
chartr('abc', '123', 'acba')
#[1] "1321"
```

Or after doing the `strsplit/unlist`, we can `match` with the `letters` to get the numeric index.

```
match(unlist(strsplit("acba", split="")), letters)
#[1] 1 3 2 1
```

---

In the OP's code, when we use `%in%` it gives a logical output i.e.

```
letters %in% unlist(strsplit("acba", split=""))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

As we can understand from the output, only the first 3 elements in the `letters` match with the `unlist` output.  So wrapping with `which` will give only the numeric index of that sequence i.e. 1, 2, 3.  But, if we use the reverse i.e.

```
 unlist(strsplit("acba", split="")) %in% letters
 #[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

and then wrap with `which`, it will show 1, 2, 3, 4.